# Maximum String Length in Intersystems Cache. Does changing it affect speed?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

I have been having `<MAXSTRING>` errors returned for some of our existing Intersystems Cache Classes

I have read [here](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCOS_types_strings_long) that by default, the length of max string is set to around 32k. Running the script `WRITE $SYSTEM.SYS.MaxLocalLength()` does confirm this at 32767, the minimum max-string length.

My question is, if we change this setting in Intersystems Cache (for example making it reach it's maximum at 3m length), will it affect the speed of the server (in general) negatively? or won't it make much difference?

Around an average of 500 people use the system regularly and make use of the class methods mentioned, if that matters

The documents mention the following:

`When a process actually uses a long string, the memory for the string comes from the operating system’s malloc() buffer, not from the partition memory space for the process. Thus the memory allocated for actual long string values is not subject to the limit set by the maximum memory per process (Maximum per Process Memory (KB)) parameter and does not affect the $STORAGE value for the process.`

However, I am not entirely sure what this means if we change the size of the string.

Answer (score 1):

We switched to long strings (3MB) a few years ago and did not notice any difference in performance.